# uninitialized constant on a simple model attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation

Probably an easy one.
Consider this simple rails model

```
class Something < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :URL, :name
  validate :name, presence: true
  validate :URL, presence: true
```

It is a complete ressource, in routes:

```
resources :something
```

created with :

```
rails generate scaffold something name:string URL:string
```

The line:

```
validate :URL, presence: true
```

keep throwing error:

```
uninitialized constant Something::URL
```

I really don't know what to do

Thanks

Comment: I think it's getting messed up because URL is a constant.  Try it again with `url` instead of `URL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It most likely doesn't like the fact that URL is uppercase.  (It thinks it's a class name).
It's against the convention and RoR is very big on conventions.